# How to use anchor tag to click on particular span

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

all sorry for the very basic or maybe a silly question but I was trying to do something which I am not sure, can be done by using an anchor tag or not. After searching over the internet I didn't find any perfect solution for that so here I am writing this question.

Problem - I want to redirect my page from `index.php` to `about.php`, and I also want to open one div that can be only visible if we click on it. How to do that using an anchor tag?

I tried - `<a href="about#my_div_id">`
unfortunately, It didn't work I think maybe because I have to also click on that particular div to make it open.
Anyone can please help me out I need some solution to do this. I am using angularJs so if it can be done by that, please help!

Comment: By adding the id of the div you want to be opened (`<a href="about#my_div_id">`) youre already halfway there. All you need to do on your target page is to read `window.location.hash` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash)) and open the div if the id's match (in JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

Could you [parse the URL in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/) on page load, open the div, and set `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to the position of the div on your page?

Something like:

```
# On page load:
#   if $parsedURL has $hash:
#     div.show()
#     window.scrollTo(div.position)
```